# What is the preferred data format for streaming pub/sub from dataflow to BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

Our process is currently a little clunky we're getting batched CSV outputs from the database, which are turned into json and streamed to pub/sub.

This is troublesome because every element in the json will be STRING format and when we try to write to bigquery it fails unless there's a type cast from within Java.

Is there any preferred typed flat-file format we could use for small batches, so that when we transfer using pub/sub, we would retain type information at a record level?

Comment: You can use readMessages method from the [PubsubIO](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.html) class in order to avoid string conversion. But you'll still need to convert Pub/Sub message to TableRow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on how exactly your pipeline is setup.

In general, `PubsubIO` has a few ways to read/write messages:

- [`PubsubIO.readAvros()`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.html#readAvros-java.lang.Class-) reads messages with payload of Avros and parses the objects;
- [`PubsubIO.readProtos()`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.html#readProtos-java.lang.Class-) does the same thing for messages with Protobuf payload;
- [`PubsubIO.readMessages()`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.html#readMessages-java.lang.Class-) gives you raw unparsed bytes;

Avros and Protos can help you simplify the serialization/deserialization step for Pubsub to avoid putting everything into a string.

But, as Yurci mentioned, you will still need to convert the payload you got from Pubsub messages to TableRows to [write them to BigQuery](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html#write).